# Running an Imported android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem with running an imported android project. In fact, when i run it i get an error from BuildConfig.java ( this file is not editable) the error is

```
"Error:(18, 69) error: illegal escape character".
```

and this is the line that the error is pointing to:

```
public static final String[] TRANSLATION_ARRAY = new String[]{"C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\values","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\af","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ar","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ca","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\cs","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\cy","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\da","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\de","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\el","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\es","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\es-ES","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\es-MX","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\es-PE","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\fa","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\fi","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\fr","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\fr-CA","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\gl","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\he","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\hi","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\hr","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\hu","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\is","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\it","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ja","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ko","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\lt","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\lv","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\mk","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ms","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\nl","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\no","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\pl","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\pt","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\pt-BR","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\pt-PT","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ro","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ru","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\sk","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\sl","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\sr","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\sv","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\sv-SE","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\ta","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\th","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\tl","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\tr","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\uk","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\vi","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\zh","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\zh-CN","C:\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\zh-TW"};
```

Comment: Please follow the guidelines in the following [article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to properly format the question and the code within

Answer (score 0):

`\g` is an illegal escape character in `"C:\gps..."`

All windows path strings need to have `\\`, for example `"C:\\"`

You should find the file that **is** editable and correct those strings

P.S. the `(18, 69)` in the error means line 18, column 69 of the file.

Comment: Where can i find such file ?

Comment: I can't accurately answer that, I don't have your project. But you can open the "Search project" dialog. Ctrl, Shift, F